# Associative array with multiple keys types, possible?

Tags: c++, containers, associative-array

Ive got a large bunch of objects (potentially 1000's) which I need to store in a container. I need to be able to find specific instances in two ways, either by its ID number (64bit unsigned int), or its name (std::string). Generally by ID will be the most common, however in some cases the name is known, but not the ID.

std::map can provide a single <-> value, however I'm not sure if having 2 sets of std::map containers, one for the Ids and another for the strings is the best approach here.

EDIT - REVISED code and error:

Ok, I figured i'd give the multi index a try since I have boost anyways, however I can't seem to get it to compile even though I've done it exactly the same as in the documentation as far as I can tell :(

test code:

```
namespace common
{
    class MyBaseClass
    {
    public:
        typedef boost::uint64_t Id;

        //name and id are constant, at least for the period im intrested in
        //when I want it in the container...
        const std::string &getName()const{return name;}
        Id getId()const{return id;}

        ...other stuff...
    };
}

class MyClass : public common::MyBaseClass
{
    ...other stuff...
};

typedef boost::multi_index_container
<
    MyClass*,
    boost::indexed_by
    <
        boost::ordered_unique<boost::const_mem_fun<MyBaseClass, MyBaseClass::Id,    &MyBaseClass::getId  > >,
        boost::ordered_unique<boost::const_mem_fun<MyBaseClass, const std::string&, &MyBaseClass::getName> >
    >
>MyClassList;
```

and your average boost template error...

> c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\aligned_storage.hpp(69) : error C2872: 'detail' : ambiguous symbol
>          could be 'boost::detail'
>          or       'boost::multi_index::detail'
>          c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\multi_index\detail\index_node_base.hpp(42) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::aligned_storage' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              size_=4,
>              alignment_=4
>          ]
>          c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\multi_index\detail\index_node_base.hpp(47) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::pod_value_holder' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              Value=MyClass *
>          ]
>          c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\multi_index\detail\ord_index_node.hpp(582) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              Value=MyClass *,
>              Allocator=std::allocator
>          ]
>          c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\multi_index\ordered_index.hpp(137) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              Super=boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base>
>          ]
>          c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\multi_index\ordered_index.hpp(119) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              KeyFromValue=boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun,
>              Compare=std::less,std::allocator>>,
>              SuperMeta=boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<2,MyClass *,boost::multi_index::indexed_by>,boost::multi_index::ordered_unique>>,std::allocator>,
>              TagList=boost::mpl::vector0,
>              Category=boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_unique_tag
>          ]
>          c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\multi_index_container.hpp(86) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              KeyFromValue=boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun,
>              Compare=std::less,
>              SuperMeta=boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1,MyClass *,boost::multi_index::indexed_by>,boost::multi_index::ordered_unique>>,std::allocator>,
>              TagList=boost::mpl::vector0,
>              Category=boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_unique_tag
>          ]
>          c:\projects\bad_angle_studios\brak3\trunk\source\source\server\MyClass.cpp(18) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::multi_index_container' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              Value=MyClass *,
>              IndexSpecifierList=boost::multi_index::indexed_by>,boost::multi_index::ordered_unique>>
>          ]
>   c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\aligned_storage.hpp(53) : error C2872: 'detail' : ambiguous symbol
>          could be 'boost::detail'
>          or       'boost::multi_index::detail'
>          c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\aligned_storage.hpp(56) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::aligned_storage::aligned_storage_imp::data_t' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              size_=4,
>              alignment_=4
>          ]
>          c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\aligned_storage.hpp(69) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::aligned_storage::aligned_storage_imp' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              size_=4,
>              alignment_=4
>          ]
>   c:\lib\c++\boost\boost\aligned_storage.hpp(73) : error C2872: 'detail' : ambiguous symbol
>          could be 'boost::detail'
>          or       'boost::multi_index::detail'
>   c:\projects\bad_angle_studios\brak3\trunk\source\source\server\MyClass.cpp(44) : error C2676: binary '[' : 'MyClassList' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Comment: I am sorry i have no dev environment on my laptop here. Does it compile if you use common::MyBaseClass instead of MyClass when typedef'ing MyClassList ?

Comment: ok, I changed it to the base class and made it use "cosnt std::string&", however now I get a different error...

Comment: ok I edited the main post to reflect he changes and new error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

boost::multi_index is the answer to your problem. See [there](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort) for more information on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative to the above, which solution you pick depends on your needs. Grab SqlLite store the data about your objects in a database and run queries for them.

Answer (score 1):

Fire Lancer, you're not qualifying Boost.MultiIndex names correctly, instead of for instance `boost::indexed_by` you've got to write `boost::multi_index::indexed_by`, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of two maps (one with ID as key, and the second with name as key), seems good to me. It is simple to implement, and will work well.

I saw that other answers recommended boost libraries. If you already use boost in your project, then it could be a good solution. If you don't - I'm not sure it is worth adding boost to your project just for this simple case.

Comment: Just so you know : when you only need a limited number of boost libraries, you can extract them using a simple tool named bcp. That way, even within boost, you don't pay for what you don't need.

Answer (score -1):

You could store the data in a std::vector and use the std::find algorithm to find your items. The find algorithm accepts different comparators, so just define one that matches ids and another that matches names.

The find algorithm is slower than std::map and std::set's find method, so if performance is a big concern then you're probably better off trading space for speed and either using 2 maps or using boost

**edit,** just had a thought. Store the data in a map, using the id as a key, as this is the common case.  Then use the std::find algorithm and a predicate that matches on name for the uncommon case.  That should reduce (but not remove)the performance issues

Comment: "slower" is an understatement, std::find is a simple O(n) forward search. If you care about optimizing for lookup time, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Terry, yes I know. However the OP doesn't mention performance requirements so I'm pointing out possibilities for them